# Suppress warning for deprecated method when there's no alternative for it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've implemented this custom class in a project:
https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

But Xcode gives a warning that the "initWithParentView" has been deprecated.

```
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithParentView:NULL];
}
```

I haven't been able to find a alternative to this method, and the class works splendid. Can someone tell me how to suppress this warning OR tell me an alternative to "initWithParentView"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please read the change notes it clearly says use init method

Edit: as it's going in the infinite loop use `[super init]` instead of `[self init]`

```
- (id)init
{
   // return [self init]; 
      return [super init];
}
```

Comment: after using  [self init]; got bad access.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. If you're overriding the custom class you should use [super init]; Else you should use [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init]

Comment: yeah me 2, seems to enter a infinite loop. Might be another problem in this custom class though

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the developer marked this as deprecated and suggests using the init method. You can edit the 3rd party library to remove this attribute or suppress it. Perhaps moving the contents of initWithParentView into init would be a better fix of the library.

```
/*!
 DEPRECATED: Use the [CustomIOS7AlertView init] method without passing a parent view.
 */
- (id)initWithParentView: (UIView *)_parentView __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
- (void) methodUsingDeprecatedStuff {
    //use deprecated stuff
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

This should suppress it.

Comment: You want `"-Wdeprecated-implementations"` for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *.h of the class tells you what to do

> /*! DEPRECATED: Use the [CustomIOS7AlertView init] method without passing a parent view. */

So if you're overriding the custom class just use

```
[self init];
```

else use

```
[[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init]
```

Comment: after using [self init]; got bad access

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. If you're overriding the custom class you should use [super init]; Else you should use [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init]